# SQL Select Case SUM()/total?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to produce a row for the total numbers of tracks in a database, currently I've got one row for one type of media and one row for another type, I just need to produce a total row for this but I can't figure it out.

I tried the below code in hopes it would work, but it comes up with the error about aggregate functions are not allowed in the GROUP BY clause

```
    SELECT CASE
    WHEN m.name LIKE '% AAC %' OR m.name LIKE 'AAC %' THEN 'AAC'
    WHEN m.name NOT LIKE '% AAC %' OR m.name NOT LIKE 'AAC %' THEN 'non-AAC'
    WHEN COUNT(m.name) <> 0 THEN 'Total'
    END AS Media, COUNT(t.MediaTypeID) AS 'Tracks'
    FROM MediaType m, Track t
    WHERE m.MediaTypeID = t.MediaTypeID
    GROUP BY Media
```

Where am I going wrong? This is done in SQLite

Comment: Do the case part in a subquery, then group by its result.

Comment: ANSI-92 has been around for 30 years now, time to stop using antiquated syntax for joins. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Yes, i use SQLite

Answer (score -1):

Use this I Modified:
But If this You want it than You use two Temp Table in your Query  this query copy and paste your system you get your answer

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN m.name LIKE '%AAC%' OR m.name LIKE 'AAC%' THEN 'AAC'
WHEN m.name NOT LIKE '%AAC%' OR m.name NOT LIKE 'AAC%' THEN 'non-AAC'
END AS Media,COUNT(t.MediaTypeID) AS 'Tracks'
into #temp FROM MediaType m, Track t
WHERE m.MediaTypeID = t.MediaTypeID
GROUP BY m.name
Select Media as 'Total' ,count(case when Media LIKE '%AAC%' OR Media LIKE 'AAC%' THEN 'AAC'
            WHEN Media NOT LIKE '%AAC%' OR Media NOT LIKE 'AAC%' THEN 'non-AAC'
            end) as 'Truck' into #temp1 from #temp
group by Media

insert into #temp1 values('Total',(Select  sum(Tracks) as 'Total'  from #temp))
Select * from #temp1
```

In this if using any aggregate function than the column name must in group by Other wise gives error

Comment: hii, it still doesn't produce a total row in this case..